# How pass a list of values to compare in a SQL Function in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, function

I have an SQL Function with the following SQL within:

```
SELECT StockID FROM (SELECT DISTINCT StockID, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateAdded DESC) AS RowNum
FROM Stock
WHERE CategoryCode LIKE @CategoryID) AS Info
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
```

I have a Parameter @CategoryID - however I need to take in a category ID such as "BA" and translated this to a list of Category IDs such as "IE","EG" etc so my WHERE clause looks like:

```
WHERE (CategoryCode LIKE 'IE' OR CategoryCode LIKE 'EG') AS Info
```

I have a Lookup Table which contains the "BA" code and then all the real category codes this means such as "IE" and "EG".
How do I have the CategoryID expand to multiple "OR" statements in my SQL Function?
I am unsure how to do this, can anyone solve this problem?

At the moment the query as shown can cope with one CategoryID such as "IE", this is done as I want a category page such as category.aspx where a parameter "BA" is passed such as category.aspx?category=BA and this page will list all items with the category codes "EG" and "IE".

The reason I need this is there is a "parent" category code which has multiple "children" category codes which are different to the parent code. I am using ASP.NET and .NET 3.5 on the front-end if this helps.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using LINQ to SQL here?

Comment: I've only used LINQ for XML so am not sure how to do it for SQL, but interesting idea.

Comment: how can your query have 2 WHERE clauses?

Comment: This is not SQL the `WHERE CategoryCode LIKE @CategoryID) AS Info` part looks like it should be a JOIN or in the select list.

Comment: I know the SQL looks a little odd, the SELECT StockID FROM (....) As Info WHERE RowNum BETWEEN etc is one and inside the brackets (....) is the other - it is based on a custom paging example which worked well - except I needed to support multiple categories - hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
WHERE CategoryCode IN (
    SELECT LookupCategoryCode 
    FROM LookupTable 
    WHERE LookupCategoryId = @CategoryId
)
```

Replacing "LookupCategoryCode", "LookupTable", and "LookupCategoryId" for the respective values in your lookup table.

Comment: I'm sure I tried something like this, but will try it again. Most combinations I was trying resulted in increased read times, I'm trying to keep these to a minimum.

Comment: With indexes in place it should be ok. However, if the performance *really* becomes critical, you could use a stored procedure to build the sql query and then execute it via sp_executesql [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188001.aspx]. But be sure to test first as you have to take into account the overhead for writing and maintaining the stored procedure.

Comment: I have the example posted - it does work but my Database Reads are 10x higher than they should be - I'm still missing something, but it does return the behaviour I need - just need to fix the tables so I can get the performance I need.

Comment: Just thought I'd update that it works now - looks like I missed an Index, did not have a Clustered Index where I should have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parameter is a common delimited list of categoryID's

Try

```
WHERE charindex(','+CategoryCode+',',','+@CatParam+',') > 0
```

Performance won't be great, but it should do the trick for you

Comment: OK, the above works for small tables and is an easy solution, but using functions like above in a WHERE clause shouldn't be used for an sizable database.   Looks like you got some additional answers, good luck with your application.